# PHP check if string is SQL timestamp

Tags: php, sql, datetime, timestamp

I need to create a PHP function that will check if a string is a SQL timestamp yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fff]. Has anyone done this? Suggestions?

Comment: Just to mention: At least mySQL understands ISO-8601 (`2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00`, see http://php.net/date with format `c`) and several others too. Depending on what you want to achieve you maybe don't need this test.

Comment: I was looking for direction, not someone to write code for me. For example - "try regular expressions" or "there's actually a function that already does that called...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$match_pattern = "/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2})/";
```

Comment: I actually used this: $match_pattern = "/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{1,4}/";